# Duplicate NULL Values on SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I was trying to JOIN two tables based on their columns using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic.document_num, wps.file_name 
FROM web_pub_subfile wps
LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic ON ic.info_card_id = wps.info_card_id
                        AND lower(ic.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%'
WHERE wps.file_name IN ('00350.dwg','00924.dwg','00960.dwg','00973.dwg');
```

I am getting output in this format

```
document_num    file_name
-------------------------
NULL            00924.DWG
NULL            00960.DWG
NULL            00973.DWG
SU-SH3A081      00960.DWG
SU-SH3A148      00973.DWG
```

Problem here is, it's not displaying anything about

```
00350.dwg
```

and displays duplicated null values on

```
00960.DWG and 00973.DWG
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
document_num    file_name
-------------------------
NULL            00350.DWG
NULL            00924.DWG
SU-SH3A081      00960.DWG
SU-SH3A148      00973.DWG
```

Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: You would seem to have no data for those rows.  Edit your question and provide sample data, as well as the desired results.

Comment: How is it duplicate ? 00960.DWG and 00973.DWG are different. Distinct applies on all columns in the select statement ... Another possibility that there are multiple values in any of the tables specified in join.

Comment: 00960.DWG has data but it shows null and even data

Comment: @Aditya  00960.DWG has two entries. one with NULL and other with value it contains

Comment: In this case what output you expect ? Null or Value ?

Comment: @Aditya If it has value then display correspondent value else NULL. But somehow it's showing NULL for the ROWS which has some data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should meet the expectation, I hope ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
         ic.document_num,
         wps.file_name
FROM     web_pub_subfile wps
         LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic ON ic.info_card_id = wps.info_card_id 
WHERE    ic.vault_name LIKE N'%su-spec-release%'
         AND ic.document_num IS NOT NULL
         AND wps.file_name IN ('00350.dwg', '00924.dwg', '00960.dwg', '00973.dwg')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ic.document_num, 
  wps.file_name 
FROM
  web_pub_subfile wps
LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic 
  ON ic.info_card_id = wps.info_card_id
  AND lower(ic.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%'
  AND wps.file_name IN ('00350.dwg','00924.dwg','00960.dwg','00973.dwg');
```

I hope this syntax can help you!